# Reading POST data - CherryPy web-framework

Tags: cherrypy

I'm new with CherryPy web-framework. I would like to know how can

I read POST data that was delivered via HTTP request's body .

Thanks,

Gabriel.

Answer (score 1):

You can either read the body of the request with `cherrypy.request.body`, `cherrypy.request.params` or if you use the default handler then, the distinction between GET and POST values is abstracted by cherrypy and you can get the values directly from the arguments:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def index(self, name, age):
    return "My name is %s and age is %s" % (name, age)
```

Your POST request must have to provide the values for `name` and `age` on the traditional forms submission.

If you are planning on using json, then use the `cherrypy.tools.json_in` decorator and read the `cherrypy.request.json` property. http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/basics.html#dealing-with-json

If you are using the `MethodDispatcher`, then there is another way to do it: http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/tutorials.html#tutorial-7-give-us-a-rest

Maybe these posts might help you:

- http://blog.joel.mx/posts/cherrypy-101
- http://blog.joel.mx/posts/cherrypy-101-method-dispatcher

Answer (score 0):

Cherrypy handles both get and post in a similar way by passing them into the function or method that is handling the request.  A good example is located at tut03_get_and_post.py in the tutorial folder within the cherrypy package.

Here is a small portion that specifically speaks to your question...

```
@cherrypy.expose
def greetUser(self, name=None):
    # CherryPy passes all GET and POST variables as method parameters.
    # It doesn't make a difference where the variables come from, how
    # large their contents are, and so on.
```